# Will non-radially radiating sound plane wave propagate forever without losing intensity?(assuming no dissipative forces)

Tags: waves, wavefunction, acoustics, intensity

I have encountered on a textbook that established the relationship that intensity is proportional to the square of displacement amplitude and the square of angular frequency. However, the equation does not introduce the 1/r^2 law of intensity (as present in a spherical sound wave).

Is it valid to assume the intensity is uniform anywhere along the plane of propagation?

Comment: Is the plane wave infinite?  Also what do you mean by 'plane of propagation'?

Answer (score 0):

See, is the same thing. Proportional to the square of amplitude, but the amplitude is proportional to the inverse of the r distance, so, as you said, the intensity is proportional to the inverse of square of the r distance